# A lecture by Rudin

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, ho.history-overview, fourier-analysis

Is it available a written version of this lecture by Rudin on the relation between Fourier analysis and the birth of set theory?

https://youtu.be/hBcWRZMP6xs

If not Rudin himself, maybe someone else has collected these ideas in an article?

Comment: Googling “Cantor Fourier series set theory” (https://www.google.com/search?q=cantor+fourier+series+set+theory&sxsrf=APq-WBthKBI5PdzMVhXQahW6LY-EIHIKKQ%3A1649410841172&source=hp&ei=GQNQYub3BuumptQPppuTkAM&oq=cantor+fourier+series+set+theory&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBADMggIIRCgARCLAzIICCEQoAEQiwMyCAghEKABEIsDMggIIRCrAhCLAzIICCEQqwIQiwM6BwgjEOoCECdQvxRYvxRg8B5oAXAAeACAAXyIAXySAQMwLjGYAQCgAQKgAQGwAQ-4AQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp#ip=1&sbfbu=1&pi=cantor%20fourier%20series%20set%20theory) gets articles by Srivastava, Kechris, Dauben and Cooke, all of which I can recommend.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte Thanks for positing this lecture.

Comment: @SimonCrase You're welcome. Great lecture indeed.

Comment: Another one by Kechris: Set theory and uniqueness for trigonometric series, [here](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~kechris/papers/uniqueness.pdf). He also has a book with Louveau on descriptive set theoretic topics around uniqueness, https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511758850.

Answer (score 8):

I extracted the written text from Rudin's lecture, it starts out like this (see below). If there is an interest, with some effort I can provide the rest of the text, but it requires some editing and I'm unsure this is what the OP wants... Perhaps just listening to the talk is good enough?

> It is a real honor to be invited to give this lecture and I'm sorry
> professor Marden couldn't be here to listen to it.
>
> I'm a bit out of my depth here today because I intend to give a talk
> which is more historical than mathematical. I was told that there
> would be many non mathematicians here in the audience and that I
> should not write too many formulas.
>
> A warning: the history of mathematics is a difficult field and it's
> one that has been neglected and I think there are good reasons for
> that. Mathematicians don't pay much attention to history. We name
> theorems after someone and sometimes that someone has something to do
> with the field and sometimes he didn't. Sometimes somebody later
> proved what the first guy should have proved if you see what he was
> really doing, and we don't ever go to the first original sources. I
> think we read what someone said about it, so mathematicians are not
> really qualified to do the history of mathematics. Historians are
> maybe even less qualified because you can't write about it unless you
> understand it and once you start studying mathematics for its own sake
> you become interested in it and you don't want to take time to go to
> the history.

Comment: Many thanks for the effort. In fact I was not so much interested in a philologically accurate written version of that particular talk, rather in a (possibly fully detailed) written version of its content. Some of the results in Matt F.'s comment are close enough.